# python twisted: enforcing a single connection per id

Tags: twisted, twisted.internet

I have a twisted server using SSL sockets and using certificates to identify the different clients that connect to the server.  I'd like to enforce the state where there is only one connection by each possible id.  The two ways I can think of is to keep track of connected ids and then not allow a second connection by the same id or allow the second connection and immediately terminate the first.  I'm trying to do the later but am having some issues (I'll explain my choice at the end)

I'm storing a list of connections in the factory class and then after the SSL handshake I compare the client's id with that list.  If it's already in that list I try to call `.transport.abortConnection()` on it.  I then want to do the normal things I do to record the new connection in my database.  However, the call to `abortConnection()` doesn't seem to call `connectionLost()` directly which is where I do my cleanup and calls to the database to say that a connection was lost.  So, my code then records that the id connected but later a call is made to `connectionLost()` resulting in the database appearing to have that id disconnected.

**Is there some sort of way to block the incoming second connection from further processing until the first connection has finished processing the disconnection?**

*Choice explanation:*  The whole reason I'm doing this is I have clients behind NATs that appear to be changing their IP address on a fairly regular basis (once a every 1-3 days).  The devices connecting will just have their connections uncleanly severed and then they try to reconnect with the new IP.  However, my server isn't notified about the disconnect and usually has to timeout the connection.  Before the server times out the connection, though, the client sometimes manages to reconnect and the server then is in a state with two apparent connections by the same client.  So, typically the first connection is the one I really want to terminate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have determined the ID of the connection, you can call `self.transport.pauseProducing()` on the "new" connection's transport, which will prevent any notifications until you call `self.transport.resumeProducing()`.  You can then call `newConnection.transport.resumeProducing()` from `oldConnection.connectionLost()`, if a new connection exists.

Comment: This would be perfect except that I'm handling processing of the certificate in `dataReceived()` (due to https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/6024).  Is there a way to handle the cert before the first call to `dataReceived()`?  If not, I suppose I could place that data in my buffer and postpone processing until the next chunk of data is received which will be after `resumeProducing`.

Comment: Just placing the data in a buffer is probably the simplest way to go about this right now.  You can add an `info_callback` but it is not likely to be worth the trouble.  Or you could submit a review response to 6024, get it merged, and then use that callback :).

Comment: I think I had changed it _from_ an `info_callback` sort of implementation because I needed the common name in my protocol object.  Also, I don't use the value for validation, I assume authentication based on the cert being properly signed by the CA.

Comment: As an aside...  Thanks for taking the time to respond to questions on StackOverflow!  I also really appreciate all the work you've done with Twisted.

Comment: I seem to be having issues with this solution:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29351778/does-pauseproducing-in-twisted-guarantee-no-more-calls-to-datareceived