# does pauseProducing() in Twisted guarantee no more calls to dataReceived()?

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.internet

This is an extension of my question here:  [python twisted: enforcing a single connection per id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29244156/python-twisted-enforcing-a-single-connection-per-id)

I'm trying to enforce a singe connection per id.  If a new connection comes in with the same id as an existing connection, I try to kill the old one and replace it with the new one.  I do that by pausing the new one, killing the old one, then un-pausing the new one.  I made the assumption that after pausing the transport on a connection I wouldn't get any further calls to `dataReceived()` but this doesn't seem to be the case.

In my logs, I recorded where I `pauseProducing` in the `dataReceived` method and then return.  Immediately (1ms!) after I have a second call to the `dataReceived` on the same object with no calls to un-pause the production.

**Are my assumptions incorrect about no more calls to `dataReceived` after `pauseProducing` or have I found a bug?**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your program is working as you describe, then yes, this is a bug.  Please file it on https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/newticket .

Comment: Did you file a ticket? Please link to it when you do.

Comment: hey..  I was reviewing old questions and just noticed this.  Unfortunately this is beyond my memory and it doesn't look like I filed a bug.